# Clubbing two scanf statements produces garbage output

Tags: scanf, c99

Can someone explain why the following same code segments produce different results just because in one, 2 scanf statements are clubbed together:

Code piece 1 (This works just fine):

```
int s_i;
double s_d;
char *s_s;

scanf("%d %lf",&s_i,&s_d);
scanf("%*[\n] %m[^\n]", &s_s);

printf("%d\n%.1lf\n%s",s_i,s_d,s_s);

free(s_s);
```

Code piece 2 (This surprisingly doesn't work plus gives a seg fault because of the free() failing):

```
int s_i;
double s_d;
char *s_s; 

scanf("%d %lf %*[\n] %m[^\n]", &s_i, &s_d, &s_s);
printf("%d\n%.1lf\n%s",s_i,s_d,s_s);

free(s_s);
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not a description of behaviour.  Can you be more specific?  Presumably in the second example the %m[ is not matching anything, so nothing is being allocated and the call to free() fails.

Comment: The second code results in segmentation fault, as is mentioned in the question.